MySQl-connector: "ошибка query_cache_size"
Я новичок в API. Cоздаю приложение API для удаленного подключения к MySQL 8.0. Но при попытке запуска возникают ошибки. Я описал эти ошибки ниже. На форумах пишут, что ошибка может быть связана с сервером или URL-адресом, но при подключении к workbench все работает корректно
user.java
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id ;
    private String login;
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int id, String login, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }
    //Getters and setters
}

userController.java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    UserService userService;
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("{vendorId}")
    public User getUserDetails(@PathVariable("vendorId") int vendorId) {
        return userService.getUser(vendorId);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String createUserDetails(@RequestBody User user) {
        userService.creteUser(user);
        return "User created successfully";
    }
}

userRepository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}

UserService
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    UserRepository userRepository;
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }


    @Override
    public String creteUser(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "Success";
    }

    @Override
    public String updateUser(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "Success";
    }

    @Override
    public String deleteUser(int id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "Success";
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(int id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id).get();

    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}

application.yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://mysql.hosting.nic.ru:3306/h406497953_db?useSSL=false
    username: h406497953_mysql
    password: *******

  jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update

исключения
ERROR 10728 --- [API_try2] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:438) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    ...more


Ваш вопрос содержит слишком много информации, которая не относится непосредственно к вашей проблеме.  Всё дело в некорректной версии драйвера, указанной в зависимостях в pom.xml или build.gradle файле, см. аналогичный вопрос на англоязычном SO: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'

@Nowhere Man Commented29, но там говорят поставить версию коннектора выше 8, но у меня стоит 8.3.0
